# What's the English translation for “Tomate Cherry Dulcemiel”?

Tags: identification, tomatoes, cultivar

What's the correct translation in English for "Tomate Cherry Dulcemiel" (Spanish)?

I could only find one link with a photo of this variety:

- https://soysuper.com/p/tomate-cherry-dulcemiel-bandeja-200-g

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Can't find a translation for that name, but these look similar to Green Grape Cherry tomatoes

Comment: The literal translation of Dulcemiel is sweet honey. Something like honey sweet cherry tomatoes. If you are looking for a species name, I don't have it. Common names do not have a 1 to 1 relationship to latin names. In the US small tomatoes like that are called "grape" tomatoes.

Comment: I'm guessing it's more S. lycopersicum and/or S. pimpinellifolium and/or S. cheesmaniae than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The name literally translates to honey sweet cherry tomato. From what I can tell by reading through Spanish news and other documents they are a tomato that has a surprising sweet flavor and are developed and marketed by a company called Syngenta. [Here is a link to a Pdf](https://www.syngenta.dk/file/1801/download?token=g-kt4aPN) describing their flavor (in english). It is on about page 18 or 19. [Here is a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTMPJrLaaPI) about the dulcemiel tomato. That is in spanish though. [I went to their site](https://www.syngenta.es/cultivos/tomate) to learn more, but didn't find anything about dulcemiel other than that they are marketing as a new snack of sorts. Sadly I could not find anything concerning a scientific name or anything like that. I hope that this info has helped a little more.